# Rows to columns based on another column ok this is it

Tags: python, pandas, merge, data-manipulation

I've merged two dataframes, but now there are duplicate rows. I want to move my rows to columns based on/grouped by a column value.

I have already merged the two dataframes:

```
df_merge = pd.merge(top_emails_df, keyword_df, on='kmed_idf')
```

The new dataframe looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'kmed_idf': ['1', '1', '1', '2', '2'], 
               'n_docs': [796, 796, 796, 200, 200],
               'email_from: ['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar'})
```

I tried to stack the dataframe:

```
newtest = df_merge.set_index(['kmed_idf']).stack(level=0)
newtest= newtest.to_frame()
```

But this only created a series. When converted to a dataframe it's still not very useful.

What I would like is a dataframe where each row is a unique value of 'kmed_idf', and the rows are now columns. Something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.Dataframe({'kmed_idf': ['1', '2', '3'],
                   'n_docs': [796],
                   'n_docs2': [796],
                   'n_docs3,: [796]})
```

This will make it easier to delete the duplicates. I've also tried using the drop duplicates pandas function, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if all you want is to remove duplicates, I think the `.drop_duplicates` function should be the way to go...

I don't know why it hadn't worked for you, but please try this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'kmed_idf': ['1', '1', '1', '2', '2'],
                   'n_docs': [796, 796, 796, 200, 200],
                   'email_from': ['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar']})

df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  email_from kmed_idf  n_docs
0        foo        1     796
3        bar        2     200
```

Comment: I guess it's because not every 'duplicate' is a duplicate. For example, two emails may be in the same column, but that means that the email was seen in multiple kmed_idf's. That is, foo in kmed_idf 1 is not a duplicate if it was in kmed_idf 2.

Comment: then `.drop_duplicates` can drop based on any subset of columns you want, using the `subset` parameter (by default it drops only duplicates that are exactly the same on all columns)